# Diseñar divs flotantes superpuestos pero responsivos

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

Lo que intento es tener divs superpuestos tal como en la imagen para una pantalla mediana, pero que se stackeen en pantallas móviles uno debajo de otro:

*(Sea con bootstrap o no la idea es que funcione XD)*

[image: Izquierda: pantalla mediana --- Derecha: pantalla pequeña]

```css
#div-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#div-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 100px;
}

#div-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="div-1" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 bg-info" style="height: 250px">

    </div>
    <div id="div-2" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 bg-secondary" style="height: 250px">

    </div>
    <div id="div-3" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 bg-dark" style="height: 250px">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Que es lo que tienes hecho hasta ahora?

Comment: Lo de la derecha con bootstrap, pero en pantallas medianas los muestro horizontalmente

Comment: @LeviArista tienes que mostrarnos lo que has intentado para poder ayudarte de mejor manera

Comment: Si no agregas tu código es difícil ayudarte, por favor lee **[ask]** y realiza el **[tour]** para que sepas como funciona el sitio.

Comment: Ok ahora subo mi codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente debes cambiar los estilos por medio de [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries) para asignarle a las cajas una posición relativa y no una absoluta en una medida de pantalla determinada:

```css
#div-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#div-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 100px;
}

#div-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 200px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px){
    #div-1,
    #div-2,
    #div-3{
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="div-1" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 bg-info" style="height: 250px">

    </div>
    <div id="div-2" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 bg-secondary" style="height: 250px">

    </div>
    <div id="div-3" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 bg-dark" style="height: 250px">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar `media-queries` para lo que necesitas. Simplemente establece tus divs con `position: relative` y pon las propiedades de `top` y `left` a 0 para que se ajusten a la pantalla y no sobresalgan.

Según la **[documentación de bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)** para pantallas con `sm` la anchura máxima es 540px, así que he tomado dicho valor como referencia.

```css
#div-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#div-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 100px;
}

#div-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 200px;
}

@media(max-width: 540px){
  #div-1, #div-2, #div-3{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="div-1" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 bg-info" style="height: 250px">

    </div>
    <div id="div-2" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 bg-secondary" style="height: 250px">

    </div>
    <div id="div-3" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 bg-dark" style="height: 250px">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transform) para posicionar los `divs` como tienes en la imagen junto con un [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries) para posicionarlos en el breakpoint que tu decidas

```css
div[class*='col-'] {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#div-1 {
  background-color: #00F;
}

#div-2 {
  background-color: #0F0;
}

#div-3 {
  background-color: #F00;
}

@media (min-width: 150px) {
  #div-2 {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(33%) translateY(-25px);
    transform: translateX(33%) translateY(-25px);
  }
  #div-3 {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(66%) translateY(-50px);
    transform: translateX(66%) translateY(-50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="div-1" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 bg-info" style="height: 250px; width: 250px;"></div>
    <div id="div-2" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 bg-secondary" style="height: 250px; width: 250px;"></div>
    <div id="div-3" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 bg-dark" style="height: 250px; width: 250px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```